# linux fedora 20 how to read data from usb drive

Tags: data-recovery, usb-drive

I installed Linux Fedora 20 on a new computer, and kept the hard drive from the old computer as a second backup of my data. The drive has two partitions, Windows XP on one and Fedora 12 on the other.

I have put the drive in a caddy with a USB connection. `ls /dev/usb` gives the line `hiddev0` (in yellow on a black background), which I presume is that drive, so, please, how do I access the data on it.

I have searched the Internet for a solution, there are a lot of suggestions, but none of them works for me.

Thanks @enedil, here is the output:

```
[Harry@localhost ~]$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for Harry: 

Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb4309008
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Device    Boot     Start       End    Blocks  Id System
/dev/sda1             63 209712509 104856223+  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2 *    209713152 210737151    512000  83 Linux
/dev/sda3      210737152 976773119 383017984  8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-swap: 2.3 GiB, 2432696320 bytes, 4751360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-root: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-home: 313 GiB, 336089579520 bytes, 656424960 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

[Harry@localhost ~]$
```

Comment: Paste output of 'sudo fdisk -l'.